# Delay Function Running at the same time as input

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to make a quick number typing program where the speed increases with each level. I am running into the problem where the `time.sleep` function runs after the input is entered leaving the user with infinite time:

```
z=int(input())  
time.sleep(t)
```

Is there a function that would run at the same time as the user is entering input and even cut them off if they don't enter in time?

Comment: I think you may take a look in `multiprocessing`.